# Wordpress: Accesing post title from content_save_pre

Tags: wordpress

i modify content when saving and need to access post title, what i have so far in functions.php

```
add_filter('content_save_pre', 'custom_content_save_pre');

function custom_content_save_pre($s) {
   // need to access post title here
   $postTitle = ? 

    // some more code here 
    return $s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globalize the $post object and you will have access to it ex:

```
add_filter('content_save_pre', 'custom_content_save_pre');

function custom_content_save_pre($s) {
   global $post;
   $postTitle = $post->title;

    return $s;
}
```

but a better hook to use would be `wp_insert_post_data` which accepts 2 parameters  `$data` and `$postarr` 
where data is an array of the post object that is needed to be returned for saving.

Comment: the former doesn't work for new posts, it seems that global variable $post is not initialised yet, but the latter works brilliantly, cheers mate